# Trying to send data from android app to mysql database, one field not working

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to send data from Android app to MySQL database, it is working fine, but only one username field is not working. Basically, app sends the questions data to DB, just one username field remains empty, other work fine.

Screenshots of DB:
[image]

[image]

**Here's the code:**
This is my MainActivity that is attempting to send

```
    package miniandroid.com.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import miniandroid.com.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView ques3s1;
    private EditText edit3s1, edit1, edit2, edit4;
    private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
    private RadioButton radioSexButton1, radioSexButton3;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private Dialog dialog;

    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 11;
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notification);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
        radioSexButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        radioSexButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg_qus1);
        edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg_qus2);
        edit4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg_qus4);
        ques3s1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qus3s1);
        edit3s1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg_qus3s1);
        ques3s1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edit3s1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("emood_veriif", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String user = prefs.getString("Username", "");
        setTitle("sMood " + user);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioSexGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("emood_veriif", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String question3s1 = prefs.getString("Question3s1", "");
                String question3s2 = prefs.getString("Question3s2", "");

                if (radioSexButton1.isChecked()) {
                    ques3s1.setText(question3s1);
                    ques3s1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    edit3s1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else if (radioSexButton3.isChecked()) {
                    ques3s1.setText(question3s2);
                    ques3s1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    edit3s1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    ques3s1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    edit3s1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        });

        Button continues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_contsubmit);
        continues.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("emood_veriif", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String question1 = prefs.getString("Question1", "");
                String question2 = prefs.getString("Question2", "");
                String question3 = prefs.getString("Question3", "");
                String question4 = prefs.getString("Question4", "");
                String question3s1 = prefs.getString("Question3s1", "");
                String question3s2 = prefs.getString("Question3s2", "");
                String user = prefs.getString("Username", "");
                String ans1 = edit1.getText().toString();
                String ans2 = edit2.getText().toString();
                String ans3 = edit3s1.getText().toString();
                String ans4 = edit4.getText().toString();
                String radioanswer;
                String question3s;
                if (radioSexButton1.isChecked()) {
                    radioanswer = "Happy";
                    question3s = question3s1;
                } else if (radioSexButton3.isChecked()) {
                    radioanswer = "Sad";
                    question3s = question3s2;
                } else {
                    radioanswer = "Normal";
                    question3s = "";
                }

                PostAnswerTask task = new PostAnswerTask();
                task.execute(user, question1, ans1, question2, ans2, question3, radioanswer, question3s, ans3, question4, ans4);
            }
        });

    }


    class PostAnswerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                String user = arg0[0];
                String question1 = arg0[1];
                String ans1 = arg0[2];
                String question2 = arg0[3];
                String ans2 = arg0[4];
                String question3 = arg0[5];
                String radioanswer = arg0[6];
                String question3s = arg0[7];
                String ans3 = arg0[8];
                String question4 = arg0[9];
                String ans4 = arg0[10];

                String link = "http://miniandroid.com/answered.php";
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("question1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(question1, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("ans1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ans1, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("question2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(question2, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("ans2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ans2, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("question3", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(question3, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("radioanswer", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(radioanswer, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("question3s", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(question3s, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("ans3", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ans3, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("question4", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(question4, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("ans4", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ans4, "UTF-8");
                URL url = new URL(link);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter
                        (conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                // Read Server Response
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                return sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new String("Unable to connect. Please contact your network provider.");
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if (result.equals("Done")) {
                progress.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnsweredActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                progress.dismiss();
                ((AlertDialog) dialog).setMessage(result);
                dialog.show();
            }


        }
    }


}
```

Here's the php file on hosting.

```
<?php
$db=new mysqli('fdb12.freehostingeu.com',
               '2099457_app',
               'kimPossible123',
               '2099457_app'); 

$stmt=$db->stmt_init();
$user=$_POST['user'];
$question1=$_POST['question1'];
$ans1=$_POST['ans1'];
$question2=$_POST['question2'];
$ans2=$_POST['ans2'];
$question3=$_POST['question3'];
$radioanswer=$_POST['radioanswer'];
$question3s=$_POST['question3s'];
$ans3=$_POST['ans3'];
$question4=$_POST['question4'];
$ans4=$_POST['ans4'];

if($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO question_answer 
                  (`Username`,`Question1`,`Answer1`,
                   `Question2`,`Answer2`,
                   `Question3`,`Answer3`,
                   `Question3_Sub`,`Answer3_Sub`,
                   `Question4`,`Answer4`)
                 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")) {
     $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss',
                        $user,$question1,$ans1,
                        $question2,$ans2,
                        $question3,$radioanswer,
                        $question3s,$ans3,
                        $question4,$ans4);
     $result=$stmt->execute();
}
if ($result) {
    echo "Done";
} else{
    echo "An Error Occured";
}
?>
```

In my registration file, everything is working fine.. The db has varchar datatype set for all fields.. I cant seem to figure out what is the problem. The index seem to be fine as well as the questions are going into the right fields.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: You might want to obfiscate your database signin credentials

Comment: You are definitely binding your paameters in the wrong order

Comment: Your screenshot conveys almost nothing of use, it's too tiny to be read, and clutters up your question. Unless you have a very specific visual problem, like a CSS issue, screenshots are almost always irrelevant.

Comment: Hi screenshot is in good resolution, please click on it to view full resolution: http://i.stack.imgur.com/esrjQ.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/6neHA.png

Answer (score 0):

As word of caution, I would use mysqli_real_escape_string on your variables before inserting them to prevent sql injection and errors with making your queries.

```
$user=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$question1=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['question1']);
$ans1=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['ans1']);
$question2=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['question2']);
$ans2=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['ans2']);
$question3=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['question3']);
$radioanswer=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['radioanswer']);
$question3s=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['question3s']);
$ans3=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['ans3']);
$question4=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['question4']);
$ans4=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['ans4']);

// then echo out the $user to see if it was passed
echo $user;
```

Then I would try printing the user name to see if it's being passed to the script correctly. If nothing prints, then the error is somewhere in the MainActivity code. Probably when the post is being prepared.

Comment: This has to be done in php, where i'll see the output? I mean where shall i echo this? sorry, I didn't understnd how to do this? :/

Comment: @UmairK This is done in the php script. You can add the `echo $user;` after the `$user = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['user']);` and you should see this output in the application because of this `if (result.equals("Done")) {
                progress.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnsweredActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                progress.dismiss();
                ((AlertDialog) dialog).setMessage(result);
                dialog.show();
            }`

Comment: @UmairK if you don't see any output when you are on the app. Then the error is in the MainActivity script.

Comment: thank you so much man, seems like i solved it.. Basically, I replaced `String user = prefs.getString("Username", "");` with `String user = userPreference.getUserName();` in my java class and it started working..  I think it wasn't getting username and storing the username as string from the java class. that's why it wasn't working.  thank you :)

Comment: @UmairK Glad to hear it! I still recommend you do the real_escape_string to your variables in the php script though. It will definitely help to stop any future errors with inserting into the database :)